# Vue JS methods not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I called the getValue function. Nothing is occurring, the data property "name" is being passed to the templating so the data bind exists. I am not sure why this is not working as I have the same syntax as the docs.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

```
      <div id = "wrapper">
        <div class = "speech-wrapper">
        <div class = "speech-bubble"> 
          <h3>Tell me what you love</h3> 
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id = "selections-container">
          <div class = "selection-item">1</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">2</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">3</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">4</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">5</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">6</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">7</div>
          <div class = "selection-item">8</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class = "button-wrap">
        <button id = "get-listings" v-on:click = "getValue"> {{name}</button>
  </div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: "test",  
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getValue: function() {
     console.log("you clicked me"); 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Bave you tried to invoke the method (use the parenthesis as though you're invoking a function)?

Comment: Like this? v-on:click = "getValue()", If so, yes I have tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as a standalone component the problem you described doesn't occur. Your problem must lie elsewhere, in code you haven't shown above.

```js
Vue.component('sample', {
  template: '<button id="get-listings" v-on:click="getValue">{{name}}</button>',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'foo',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getValue() {
      console.log('get value');
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sample></sample>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to where I should start to look, I am getting no errors in the console as to alude to the problem.

Comment: @simon share the actual code how u used in ur script. that will help to trouble shoot

Comment: Its part of a PWA so its quite a lot of stuff in the project. I could host the whole thing into a git hub repo? We are working on this for uni in a team of two and we have made no progress all day :D

Comment: I have put the whole zipped project in to here if you get a chance mate.

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XIMGzKm4jhP1d925vpt8dtfgwJXnC8DP)

Comment: The problem was actually with CSS!